How to extract the VID PID from USB devices in powershell?
I'm trying to list the VID:PID for connected and active USB devices using powershell, in hope to get something similar to lsusb in *nix based OS's.
I can get a table with the devices I'm interested in, but I'm not able to extract the VID, PID and bInterfaceNumber (that I call IFn) independently and show the values. The output is given in the form:
USB\VID_v(4)&PID_d(4)&MI_z(2)
Where:

z(2) is the interface number that is extracted from the "bInterfaceNumber"
field of the corresponding interface descriptor, presumably in the range [00-99].

The code I tried:
(Get-PnpDevice -PresentOnly | Where-Object { $_.Class -match 'USB' -AND $_.InstanceId -match '^USB'}) | Select-Object Status, @{n="VID"; e={($_.InstanceId -match '.*VID_(?<vid>[0-9A-F]{4})')}},Class,FriendlyName,InstanceId,Manufacturer | ft -AutoSize

# Output
Status   VID Class     FriendlyName           InstanceId                                              Manufacturer
------   --- -----     ------------           ----------                                              ------------
OK     False USB       USB Root Hub (USB 3.0) USB\ROOT_HUB30\4&1CDD8EC&0&0                            (Standard USB HUBs)
OK     False USB       USB Root Hub (USB 3.0) USB\ROOT_HUB30\4&7B32CF2&0&0                            (Standard USB HUBs)
OK      True USBDevice RTL2838UHIDIR          USB\VID_0BDA&PID_2838\00000001                          Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
OK      True USB       USB Composite Device   USB\VID_30C9&PID_00AC\01.00.00                          (Standard USB Host Controller)
OK      True USBDevice APP Mode               USB\VID_30C9&PID_00AC&MI_02\6&195555CF&2&0002           WinUsb Device

But I want the actual VID and not just if it was a match. In addition I need 2 more columns showing the PID and IFn.
The RegEx for that, is something like this, but not sure as MI_nn may not be present:
$_.InstanceId -match '.*VID_(?<vid>[0-9A-F]{4})&PID_(?<pid>[0-9A-F]{4})&MI_(?<ifn>[0-9]{2}).*'

Q: How can I use this with a hash, and then use correctly within the expression?

When you use -match (or it's variants) against a single input string, the $Matches automatic variable is updated in the current scope, populated with any captured value - so use that to grab VID value:
@{Name = 'VID'; Expression = { if ($_.InstanceId -match '.*VID_(?<vid>[0-9A-F]{4})'){ $Matches['vid'] }}

